# Bulk resolve merge conflicts in tfs

Tags: tfs, merge-conflict-resolution

I have my source control data on a separate partition.
When I rebuilt my machine I pointed my work space to the old location. 
Then I did a get latest and was confronted by a lot of merge conflicts that couldn't be resolved by auto merge (A non version controlled file or writable file by the same name already exists locally).

While I can resolve each conflict there are a lot of them.
Can I bulk resolve these conflicts?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this is a pain don't do this.
Shelve all your change-sets so you can wipe the mapped folders and start again.

To bulk resolve just select all and click the resolution.

It is my opinion that the UI does not make it clear you are resolving all item.